# javaFX : How to periodically load information from db and show it on a Label?

Tags: database, timer, javafx

I want to execute a method periodically, this method get informations from  database it show it into a label, I tried the following code :

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 //update information
                 miseAjour();
             }
            }, 0, 2000);
```

when i run the main program,  the background service run also normaly but when the informations changes on db i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0
```

And this is the code of  method miseAjour :

```
public void miseAjour(){
    try {

        dbConnection db = new dbConnection();
        Connection connect = db.connectiondb();
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt= connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) as nbrAderent  FROM  gss_aderent ");  
        int nbrAderent = rs.getInt("nbrAderent"); 
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        connect.commit();
        connect.close();
        main_nbrAdrTot.setText(nbrAderent + "");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   }
```

Comment: this should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916640/javafx-not-on-fx-application-thread-when-using-timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i resolved the problem ,here is the code :

```
public class TimerServiceApp {
    public void start() throws Exception {
        TimerService service = new TimerService();
        service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(10));
        service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                main_nbrAdrTot.setText(t.getSource().getMessage());
            }
        });
        service.start();
    }



    private class TimerService extends ScheduledService<Integer> {
        private final StringProperty  nbrTotAderent = new SimpleStringProperty();


         public final void  setTotalAderentNumber(String value ) {
             nbrTotAderent.set(value);
         }


        public String getTotalAderentNumber() throws SQLException  {
        String nbrAderent = null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        Connection connect=null;

        try {
        dbConnection db = new dbConnection();
        connect = db.connectiondb();
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt= connect.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) as nbrAderent  FROM  gss_aderent ");  
        nbrAderent = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("nbrAderent")); 
        connect.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally {
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        connect.close();
        }
        System.out.println(" Total aderent number updated to :" + nbrAderent + " Aderents ");
        return nbrAderent;
        }

        protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
            return new Task<Integer>() {
                protected Integer call() throws SQLException {

                    nbrTotAderent.setValue(getTotalAderentNumber());
                    updateMessage(getTotalAderentNumber());
                    return  Integer.parseInt(getTotalAderentNumber());
                }
            };
        }
    }
} `
```

and i called this service by  :

```
 TimerServiceApp s = new TimerServiceApp();
        s.start();
```

i dont know if the solution is optimised but it work :) thank you @ItachiUchiha i took the solution from yout answer in the following  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853735/simple-example-for-scheduledservice-in-javafx/27858823#27858823)

Answer (score 0):

You can Timer for this, but I would recommend to use the JavaFX provided API called as [ScheduledService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

ScheduledService is made to `execute the same Task at regular intervals` and since it creates a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) internally, there are API which help you to bind the value to the UI controls.

```
ScheduledService<Object> service = new ScheduledService<Object>() {
     protected Task<Object> createTask() {
         return new Task<Object>() {
             protected Object call() {
                 // Call the method and update the message
                 updateMessage(miseAjour());
                 return object; // Useful in case you want to return data, else null
             }
         };
     }
 };
 service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(10)); //Runs every 10 seconds

 //bind the service message properties to your Label
 label.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty()); // or use your label -> main_nbrAdrTot
```

Inside the dbcall method `miseAjour`, return the value that you have fetched and you want to update the label with :

```
public String miseAjour(){
    String nbrAderent = null;
    try {
        dbConnection db = new dbConnection();
        Connection connect = db.connectiondb();
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt= connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) as nbrAderent  FROM  gss_aderent ");  
        nbrAderent = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("nbrAderent")); 
        connect.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally {
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        connect.close();
    }
    return nbrAderent;
}
```

Comment: thank you @ItachiUchiha for your fast and organised answer but can you please say me why are you using a not declared  variable in call method  witch is the variable  object, i'm getting error in this issue.

Comment: You can use `return null` instead of `return object`.

Comment: i have no error on code but the label remain empty withou any value , the method miseAjour is never excuted !

Comment: Did you start the service? You can view a [complete example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853735/simple-example-for-scheduledservice-in-javafx/27858823#27858823).

Comment: Yes  it is started and i'm still getting nothing on label , i triyed to print the value :  `service.messageProperty().getValue()` on console  this ruturn no value. :(