# How to create a time delay using JavaFX Concurrency package, task and service?

Tags: multithreading, service, javafx, task, sleep

I have a JavaFx program which I have created a task that downloads data from a webserver. The task is also surrounded by a service, so that the task can be recalled. What I am attempting to do is call the task/service every 30 seconds, to refresh the data. I have attempted to achieve this through inputting a 30 second sleep thread in the succeeded method in the service class. It works but also creates a delay at the start of the service. How do I call the service every 30 seconds but wont delay the service at the start of the application?

Comment: You are looking for [ScheduledService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html). Check this for an example - [Simple example for 'ScheduledService' in Javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853735/simple-example-for-scheduledservice-in-javafx)

Comment: Thanks @ItachiUchiha for the help! I have changed our service to a ScheduledService now, and have, put in the new line of code in our main thread
    'service.setPeriod(Duration.(30));'

However it is coming up with an error "Cannot Find Symbol".
I have also tried 

'service.setPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(30));'

But that also comes up with the same error

Comment: I think you are looking for [Duration.seconds()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Duration.html#seconds-double-).

Comment: Solved it using Platform.runLater()